# How do I properly use PUT for updating something?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to learn xamarin forms. I have this existing database that I wanted to be accessed by an App. Here I want to update something using web api/REST, I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest) guide for consuming REST. Unfortunately it's not working and I don't even know why.
How do I properly use PUT for updating something and what is wrong here?

WEB API class:

```
class GuestAcc
{
    public string RefCode { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Xamarin Model:

```
public class GuestAcc
{
    public string RefCode { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

GuestAccountsController:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateBalance(GuestAcc guestAcc)
    {
        var guestAccounts = db.GuestAccounts.First(x => x.ReferenceCode == guestAcc.RefCode);
        guestAccounts.Balance = guestAccounts.Balance - guestAcc.Price;
        db.Entry(guestAccounts).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Xamarin form:

```
 private async void btn_proceed_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            GuestAcc guestAcc = new GuestAcc();
            guestAcc.Price = 125;
            guestAcc.RefCode = "user123";
            var guestAccountURL = "http://192.168.8.100:56750/api/UpdateBalance/";
            var uri_guestAccount = new Uri(string.Format(guestAccountURL, string.Empty));
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(guestAcc);
            var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            response = await client.PutAsync(uri_guestAccount, content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Notice", "Success", "Ok");
            }
 }
```

Comment: `Unfortunately it's not working and I don't even know why` That isn't enough details. You need to tell us **everything** you know. Is the server side being hit? Is the client side throwing an exception? Is the server side throwing an exception? Does it work if you do a request from Postman rather than Xamarin? Are you running on IIS? _It is **crucial** that you answer **every one** of those questions._

Comment: Try adding [HttpPut] to UpdateBalance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct HTTP verb either in the action name or as an attribute to the method. like

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateBalance(GuestAcc guestAcc)
{
    var guestAccounts = db.GuestAccounts.First(x => x.ReferenceCode == guestAcc.RefCode);
    guestAccounts.Balance = guestAccounts.Balance - guestAcc.Price;
    db.Entry(guestAccounts).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

or in the name like

```
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]    
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutBalanceAsync(GuestAcc guestAcc)
{
    var guestAccounts = db.GuestAccounts.First(x => x.ReferenceCode == guestAcc.RefCode);
    guestAccounts.Balance = guestAccounts.Balance - guestAcc.Price;
    db.Entry(guestAccounts).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: Your explanation on Http Status 204 is wrong. Read the docs on the link you gave

Comment: Sorry, my bad, failed to click on the link, my understanding was wrong